# Comparison of resultset of two database

Tags: java

How can i compare two result set coming from two different database.I have a table in sybase and the same table in oracle now i transfer the oracle table data to sybase table . now i have to write a java program which will compare two result set and find if any data is missing. if so then update the missing data in an excel . please help.

Comment: What would you do? What is the **specific** problem stopping you?

Comment: i don't know how to compare resulset from two different database

Comment: From your question, I can only assume that you have never used Java when working with databases, and now you have language-related problem? But, it seems like a simple problem to resolve: google-up some examples for connecting to DBs from Java and retrieving the `ResultSet`s, think of an algorithm to iterate through these sets and match the data, and that's it. Of course, if the tables are large it may require additional work.

Answer (score 1):

If you do know **how to iterate** over a single `ResultSet` object, then you can compare these 2 result sets element by element.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both tables in SyBase, why use Java? This is actually a task for which SQL is ideal :-)

I assume the tables are identical in structure and have a sensible primary key? If so, it is simply a matter of doing left and right outer joins between the two tables and there you have the difference...

Cheers,

Comment: no both the tables are not in sybase . i have a table in sybase nw the database is changed to oracle. so  all the data are send to oracle table.

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted the "... i transfer the oracle table data to sybase table..." wrongly then. Still, if you have that possibility it might still be a lot faster than going the code-route.

Comment: but how? can you tell me please??